# Use opencv.js in react native

Tags: react-native, opencv

I want to integrate opencv with react-native. I found opencv.js exists but it only supports web ( I am supposing).

Can I integrate opencv.js with react-native? If yes then how do i import it? I found this [link](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/de6/tutorial_js_nodejs.html) to  use opencv.js with node.js. But it seems it requires a lot of node specific libraries to run.

Answer (score 0):

use `react-native-opencv3` package by

```
yarn add react-native-opencv3
```

and use open cv functions imported from `react-native-opencv3`